# UnimplementedError: Graph execution error: Detected at node 'huber_loss/Cast' defined at (most recent call last): How can I solve this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, execution, training-data

When trying to run some one code for counting leaves, I got this problem at the training step. I use gg colab to run this code take much time but still do not know how to solve this. Anyone can help me ?

**You can see my code here:**
https://github.com/ThanhHung2112/Machine_learning/blob/main/Counting_leaves.ipynb

Thiss is the error:

```
UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'huber_loss/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-68-3176974e15d1>", line 8, in <module>
      validation_data = val_dataset
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1694, in huber
      y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=backend.floatx())
Node: 'huber_loss/Cast'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node huber_loss/Cast}}]]
  (1) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_52546]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the training variables are in the correct shape as the model input layer.